# Why are there not bang methods for some string methods like underscore, tableize ...?

Tags: ruby

I just regonzied that there are some string methods without an equivalent bang method

```
formated_index = formated_index.tableize
```

I assumed I just can write ...

```
formated_index.tableize!
```

... but I cann't :-(

Same for `String::underscore` and other `String::*ize` methods.

So some exist while others like `downcase!` or `next!` exist. Why is this so inconsistent handled in ruby?

Comment: Doubt there's a reason.

Comment: But good ruby code should always have a reason. Because of the principle of least surprise, there must be a bang method or a good reason why not.

Comment: That doesn't mean all code is well thought out. Sometimes you write code to get something done, not to adhere to every principle possible.

Comment: The Principle of Least Surprise (POLS) isn't a catch-all for everyone. Matz says it's the principle of least surprise *for him*, and for developers who are sufficiently well versed in Ruby. It's not a rule, it just means things should make sense if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

`tableize`, `humanize`, `pluralize` are not Ruby methods but ActiveSupport extensions to String class which do not have bang variants.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but that rises the question why there are no bang variants in ActiveSupport?